# How to add a table break?

Tags: tabularx, tcolorbox

I would like to add a break in my table when changing the page. Try breakable but it doesn't work. I am new to Latex. Please help.

```
  \documentclass[table]{article}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \usepackage{booktabs}

  \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

  \tcbset{rtab/.style={
  freelance,
  frame code={
    \path[top color=black,bottom color=black] %color de relleno cabecera
      ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north west) --
      ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north east) {[rounded corners]--
      ([yshift=2pt]interior.north east) --
      ([yshift=2pt]interior.north west)} -- cycle;
    \path[top color=black!1,bottom color=black!20] %Color de relleno de la tabla
      ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north west) --
      ([yshift=-#1*(\baselineskip+2pt)]interior.north east) --
      (interior.south east) --
      (interior.south west) -- cycle;
    \path[top color=black,bottom color=black!0.5] %color relleno linea inferior de la tabla
      (interior.south west) --
      (interior.south east) {[rounded corners]--
      ([yshift=-4pt]interior.south east) --
      ([yshift=-2pt]interior.south west)} -- cycle;
    },
  interior code={},
   }
  }

  \newcommand\fuentecabecera[1]{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}}}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    rtab=1, width=6cm,%cambiar rtab= 0,1,2,3... para aumentar lineas de cabecera además colocar el ancho requerido con width=6cm.
    tabularx*={\arrayrulecolor{black}}%
      {>{\bfseries}M{2.5cm}|M{2.5cm}}
  ]
  \fuentecabecera{Denominador} & \fuentecabecera{Se lee:} \\
  \\[-1.7ex]
  2 &  Medios \\ \midrule
  3 &  Tercios \\ \midrule
  4 &  Cuartos \\ \midrule
  5 &    Quintos \\ \midrule
  6 &    Sextos \\ \midrule
  7 &    Sétimos \\ \midrule
  8 &    Octavos \\ \midrule
  9 &    Novenos \\ \midrule
  10 & Décimos \\ \midrule
  11 & Onceavos \\ \midrule
  100 & Céntesimos \\ \midrule
  1000 & Milésimos 
  \end{tcolorbox}


  \end{document}
```

The problem is that it leaves a lot of space when the table goes to the next page.
[image]

Thank you very much for your help...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! YOu should use `longtable` and `breakable` suport from `tcolorbox` (see sect. 18: Library "breakable").